# AjaxFileUpload inside a Panel not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, file-upload, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Hello I'm having trouble getting the AjaxFileUpload control to work properly.  I have it working properly on a different page, using identical code, but not inside of a panel on this page.  It functions properly and allows me to select files and hits the 'OnUploadComplete' function, however it is crashing on the .SaveAs giving me NullReferenceException.  I put the ghostupload control at the start of the page at the recommendation after finding others with similar problems and this is necessary or the control doesn't work at all.

aspx code (outside panel)

```
<div style="display:none"> <AjaxControlToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="ghostAjaxFileUpload"     runat="server" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload_UploadComplete" /></div>
```

aspx code (inside panel)

```
<AjaxControlToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="ajaxupload1" runat="server" ThrobberID="loader123" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg" MaximumNumberOfFiles="2" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload_UploadComplete" /><asp:Image id="loader123" ImageUrl="images/loading.gif" Style="display:None" runat="server" />
```

aspx.cs code

```
protected void AjaxFileUpload_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
    //...other logic/file checking (working fine)
    ajaxupload1.SaveAs(appSession.GlobalImageFolder + appSession.GlobalProductImageFolder + filename);
    }
```

Been working on this one all day and it's got me stumped!  I really like the AjaxFileUpload so I'm hoping I won't have to resort to a different upload control.  Really appreciate any help on this one!

Cheers,
Jordan

Comment: Show more markup and code-behind.

Comment: Anything specifically you're looking for? I've included all relevant code @yuriy

Comment: I'm not sure where exactly error. Show panel which holds upload control, show Page_Load code

Comment: @Yuriy There is no code in the Page_Load related to the control.  The control is failing on the OnUploadComplete function (specifically the SaveAs).  The control is inside of a panel which is set to visible false on the page load but during logic is turned on. <asp:Panel ID="Products_ListOwnProducts" runat="server" Visible="false">

Comment: I've resorted temporarily to a regular asp:FileUpload control as this works fine but I'd really rather use this control if someone has any idea!

Comment: You are so sure of which code has relation to you problem and which doesn't that I'm wonder why you didn't resolve this issue on yourself. Moreover, be warned that when `UploadComplete` event raised, `Page.IsPostback` property equals to `false`. Maybe you need to review  a logic for turning off and on parent panel vivibility